# How remove parts of structure

Tags: matlab, structure

I have a structure like the picture with empty boxes and I would like to obtain my structure without these empty boxes.

I don't understand how to do this without remove the totality of rows which contain an empty box.

For example : I think that the rows 10 for Time_Left and Steps_Left have to replace respective boxes of the row 6

[image: Structure]

```
% Extraction of Right Steps
cpt = 1;
for i = 1 : length(Data)
    if Data.Insoles(i,3) > 0
        Steps(cpt).Time_Right(i) = Data(i,1); 
        Steps(cpt).Steps_Right(i) =  Data(i,3);
     end

    if Data(i,3)==0 && Data(i+1,3) > 0
        cpt = cpt +1;
    end
end


for j= 1: length(Steps.Insole)
     for k = size(Steps(j).Steps_Right,2):-1:1
         if Steps(j).Steps_Right(k) < Parameters.Threshold
            Steps(j).Steps_Right(k) = [];
            Steps(j).Time_Right(k) = [];
         end
     end
end

for f= length(Steps):-1:1
         if isempty([Steps(f).Steps_Right])
            Steps(f)=[];
         end
end


% Extraction of Left Steps
cpt = 1;
for i = 1 : length(Data)
    if Data(i,2) > 0
        Steps(cpt).Time_Left(i) = Data(i,1); 
        Steps(cpt).Steps_Left(i) =  Data(i,2);
     end

    if Data(i,2)==0 && Data(i+1,2) > 0
        cpt = cpt +1;
    end
end


for j= 1: length(Steps)
     for k = size(Steps(j).Steps_Left,2):-1:1
         if Steps(j).Steps_Left(k) < Parameters.Threshold
            Steps(j).Steps_Left(k) = [];
            Steps(j).Time_Left(k) = [];
         end
     end
end

for f= length(Steps):-1:1
         if isempty([Steps(f).Steps_Left])&&isempty([Steps(f).Steps_Right])
            Steps(f)=[];
         end
end
```

Comment: This looks like a table, not a structure...

Comment: No it's à structure I build it

Comment: If you 'built' it then you should have the code which shows how you did so. Show us that code (or a relevant subsection) and we can help you create the structure without the empty elements.

Comment: I can show you this part of code but I can't share the data to run it

Comment: what does `class(yourvariable)` return?

Comment: `class([s.Time_Left]) = double `
`class(s) = struct`

Comment: yes of course ->  I use R2017a version

Comment: What's wrong with those empty arrays? This is just the representation for empty fields. Do you want to have another representation for empty fields?

Comment: At the end I would like to obtain a structure with the same number of line for my 4 fields (it's the case without empty boxes)

Comment: @Mac. you want to *fill* the structures?

Comment: I can not imagine what it would be like with fill the strucute :-/. fill how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you want.

You appear to have an *array of structures*, and in this array, each structure must have the same fields.

example:

```
structure.a=1;
structure.b=2;
a(1)=structure;
structure.c=4;
a(2)=structure;

> "Subscripted assignment between dissimilar structures."
```

Your only option would be to have a *cell array of structures*, but whether this is a better option than just having empty fields, that you can only answer (depends on what you are doing with it).

---

You know there is a function `isempty` to check whether an array is empty or not, right?